# Deflection of String

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, wave-equation

I am trying to determine u(x,t) for a string of length L=1 and c^2=1 when the initial velocity is 0 and initial deflection with small k(.01) is as follows:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i1xdrpoepa

Answer (score 1):

The displacement $u(x,t)$ of the string is described by the wave equation for $t \ge 0$ and $0 \le x \le 1$:
$$
               u_{tt} = c^{2}u_{xx},\\ u(x,0)=f(x),\;\;u_{t}(x,0)=0,\\ u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0.
$$
The constant $c > 0$ is a physical constant associated with the properties of the string.

You start by looking for separated solutions $T(t)X(x)$ with separation parameter $\lambda$:
$$
                       \frac{T''(t)}{c^{2}T(t)} =\lambda = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)},\\
                   T'(0) =0,\;\;\; X(0)=X(1)=0.
$$
The parameter $\lambda$ is determined by the $X$ equation because of $X(0)=X(1)=0$. You can't get non-trivial combinations of the hyperbolic functions to vanish at two endpoints, and $\lambda=0$ doesn't work either. So $\lambda < 0$ is required, and you can just about spot the solutions in $x$:
$$
                    X_{n}(x) = \sin(n\pi x),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
That means $\lambda = -n^{2}\pi^{2}$ and the corresponding $T$ solutions are
$$
                     T_{n}(t) = \cos(nc\pi t).
$$
(Any $\sin(nc\pi t)$ terms are eliminated by $T_{n}'(0)=0$.)

So the proposed solution is
$$
                  u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\cos(nc\pi t)\sin(n\pi x)
$$
The final condition to be matched is $u(x,0)=f(x)$, where
$$
    f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                      x, & 0 \le x \le 1/4 \\
                     1/4, & 1/4 \le x \le 3/4 \\
                     1-x, & 3/4 \le x \le 1
                   \end{array}\right. .
$$
This gives you a Fourier series problem:
$$
          f(x) = u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\sin(n\pi x)
$$
The $\sin(n\pi x)$ are mutually orthogonal. So, if you multiply both sides by $\sin(m\pi x)$ and integrate over $[0,1]$, all of the integrals involving $\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)$ vanish except for $n=m$. Thus,
$$
  \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\sin(m\pi x)dx = A_{m}\int_{0}^{1}\sin^{2}(m\pi x)dx = \frac{1}{2}A_{m}
$$
Once you have the constants $A_{m}$, you're done:
$$
\begin{align}
    A_{m} & = 2\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\sin(m\pi x)dx \\
    & = 2\int_{0}^{1/4}x\sin(m\pi x)dx \\
    & + 2\int_{1/4}^{3/4}\sin(m\pi x)dx \\
    & + 2\int_{3/4}^{1}(1-x)\sin(m\pi x)dx
\end{align}
$$